# Excel - find and remove text, surrounded by varying characters

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've got an Excel file with ~5,500 rows of inventory items. One cell in each row is a description field and contains HTML.

Some (but not all) of these cells contain a link formatted something like this:

```
<p><a href="back-to-site-url"><span class="caps">Back to Website<span></a></p>
```

Some of them have the `<span>` tags in them, others do not. The anchor URL is also varying among all of the occurrences of this link.

Is there any logic which would remove this link? A straight find and replace wouldn't work, although possibly sampling 100 random cells, seeing which link combinations exist and performing the find and replace on those may work.

What about a macro? Is it possible to find each cell containing "Back to Website" and remove the text with some sort of conditional?

Comment: So, what do you want to do? Find each "Back to Website" in cells and then delete everything between "href=" and the next ">"?

Comment: yes exactly, ideally removing the `<p>` tags and everything inbetween. But in these cells there will be other `<p>` tags, so only the tags that contain "Back to Website".

Comment: @javy Can we some more *before* and *after* examples?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AkE0gy8aNy_qdGZKcDZrV1YxTWI2MTR2T2w1Y3hHdmc&usp=sharing there are 2 such scenarios I found just checking a couple rows randomly.

Answer (score 1):

Nested `SUBSTITUTE`s could work for you. For example, I have a list of MAC addresses which may be formatted with one of three delimiters (colon, dash, space,) or no delimiter at all. To make these consistent, I do the following so that they're all non-delimited:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""),":",""),"-","")
```

**SUBSTITUTE** takes up to four arguments, but this only needs the first three (which are mandatory anyway).

- ***text*** is the first argument, and represents the text you want to work on. Here, the innermost `SUBSTITUTE` targets A1. Then, the next `SUBSTITUTE` towards the outside will take the result of the first, and so on.
- ***old_text*** is the second argument. This is the text within *text* that you want substituted. The innermost `SUBSTITUTE` above is handling spaces, the next one towards the outside handles colons, and the outermost one deals with dashes. If `SUBSTITUTE` can't find *old_text* in *text*, it doesn't care - it just does nothing.
- ***new_text*** is the last argument. This is the value for the replacement text. Since I just want to strip out the delimiters with the above formula, it uses a null string - "".

Obviously, cleaning up the stuff you're dealing with is going to be a lot more complicated. However, there should be a finite and relatively limited amount of values that actually need cleaning up. Hopefully this will get you headed in the right direction.

Comment: Sounds like this could work, I'm going to give it a shot. Thanks!